# C - Cannot access saddr

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, netfilter

I am trying to handle simple packet inspection with netfilter hooks.

Declaration seems fairly straightforward:

```
unsigned int hook_func(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff *skb, 
            const struct net_device *in,
            const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
{

     struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);

}
```

And I can access the protocol portion of the network header

`iph->protocol == IPPROTO_TCP`

However

`iph->saddr`

Fails. Any suggestions? I feel as this is a fairly simple error on my part, but all the examples follow either this method or they simply use

`struct iphdr *iph = ip_hdr(skb);`

I get the same behavior with both methods.  I have looked through skbuff.h for any clues but havn't had any luck.

**EDIT:**

Could this have to do with they way I am accessing it? Right now for debugging I am merely trying to print the value out using:

`printk(KERN_DEBUG "%pI4", iph->saddr);`

Comment: Do you get an error message? What is it?

Comment: it kills the machine.. I usually just reset the snapshot in my vm. There are no compile time errors. Is there a way to get an error message after a kernel crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%pI4` takes an address, so you are reading possibly invalid memory. Use `&iph->saddr` instead.

Comment: This was it! Thanks for the catch.